# Open Source Shopping Cart that Allows me to Add Many Attributes to Items?

Tags: e-commerce

I am trying to find a shopping cart that will allow me to add different attributes to an item then be able to save those attributes before the customer puts the item into the cart.

Similar to how http://folsomskis.com/custom has done it. They have a LOT of graphics for their skis, however, they do not have an add to cart option once everything is updated for the ski, they just have you fill out the form...

Any thoughts or ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in open source shopping cart will not allow you the entry of attributes. because it is having limited application. there are lot of companies in the market provides you the shopping cart solution, you can integrate the solution with M-commerce, F-commerce and partners like eBay, amazon and Other. there is a solution called " Nichesuite" from Nichepro technologies provides you a most affordable, user-friendly solution. With NicheSuite, you can capture and synchronise your database digitally for future reference. NicheSuite also allows a group of social media users to blog about products, and it also has 3D visualisation!